# Select distinct records order by clause

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table

```
Table1
(
  id bigint
  , name nvarchar(50)
)
```

This table can have same name with different case name.

```
Insert into Table1
(Select 1, 'Ram')
(Select 2, 'Ram')
(Select 3, 'Ram')
(Select 4, 'Ram')
(Select 5, 'ra')
(Select 6, 'ram')
(Select 7, 'RAM')
(Select 8, 'RAM')
```

Now I need to select all the distinct name by case and have the minimum id number. The result should be

```
1, Ram
6, ram
7, RAM
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this:

```
SELECT  t.id
        , t.name
FROM    (
        SELECT  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY name COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AI ORDER BY id) num
                ,*
        FROM    Table1
) t
WHERE   num = 1 AND name = 'ram'
ORDER BY t.id
```

Notice that I added the 'COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AI' - this tells SQL Server what type of string comparison to perform, if your database collation is case-sensitive (CS) you can remove this part of query, but if your collation is case-insensitive (CI) you have to use the case sensitive version of your collation (I used `Latin1_General` case sensitive, accent insensitive).

Comment: i was wondering why do you need to use common table expression with some analytical function when this can be simply done using simple query using `MIN` and `GROUP BY` clause.

Comment: @JW In this case subquery is not a performance problem, this approach even has a slightly smaller cost in the execution plan then the `GROUP BY` approach. If you ask me both approaches are equally readable.

Comment: OK, I added `WHERE name = 'ram'` to JW's query and it decreased query cost, which means `GROUP BY` approach uses less code and has slightly smaller cost so it's a way to go. I would suggest OP to use that `GROUP BY` solution.

Answer (score 5):

```
SELECT MIN(ID) ID, name COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS Name
FROM   table1
WHERE  name <> 'ra'
GROUP  BY name COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS
ORDER  BY ID
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/a039f/5)
- [TSQL COLLATE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184391.aspx)
- [Selecting a SQL Server Collation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144250%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

Comment: Yes, but OP doesn't want `ra` in the result set for some reasons

Comment: @AndreyGordeev you can simply add this in the `WHERE` condition `WHERE name <> 'ra'`

Answer (score 0):

```
select min(id),name  from Table1group by UPPER(name) ASC
```